# Why doesn't Safari 15 on Desktop respect my theme-color setting?

Tags: html, safari, mobile-safari

My site ( https://knpw.rs ) has a tag in the `<head>` as such:

```html
<meta name="theme-color" content="#F9F9F9"/>
```

On Safari Mobile (iOS) the `theme-color` is respected for the header:

[image]

But on Safari Desktop, the `theme-color` is not respected:

[image: Safari Desktop knpw.rs]

Compare to https://registry.terraform.io which has `theme-color` set to `#5c4ee5`:

[image: Terraform Registry desktop]

Which is also respected on mobile:

[image]

Why isn't my `theme-color` respected on Safari 15 Desktop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be because your theme-color value is resulting in a bad contrast for the current system preferred layout (too bright for the user’s choice of having all dark layout). I think it is mentioned in this video from Apple Developer, that Safari will ignore your custom value if it doesn’t meet a certain threshold:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10029/

This article is also mentioning that behavior/limitation: https://css-tricks.com/meta-theme-color-and-trickery/

To resolve this, you need to add 2 theme-color values, one for each preferred color scheme dark/light, and stay within the thresholds. Example:

```html
<meta name="theme-color" content="#f9f9f9" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#872e4e" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
```

Comment: That appears to be the case, some colors are working and others are not. I understand why Safari is doing this, it's just a shame Safari doesn't have some sort of warning in the console about this and seemingly no tooling to help determine colors that won't get clobbered.

Comment: Agreed, it‘s very tedious to debug invalid color values.

Comment: Spent a long time experimenting:

In Safari 16 for desktop the theme-color is not applied unless safari layout is set to "compact" in the preferences.

In iPadOS, the "compact tab bar" must be selected under Settings > Safari.

In iOS, you need to enable the "Allow Website Tinting" setting under Settings > Safari.

Answer (score 7):

Some colors are not displayed properly on macOS Safari 15, especially when you use dark appearance and the theme color is too light.

I built this small tool to preview if `theme-color` working properly.

> ⚠️ Note: When using `separate tab` mode, theme-color won't be applied to browser.

link: https://roger.zone/theme-color-preview/

[image: Safari 15 Theme Color Preview]

Comment: This is a cool idea but not working as of March 2022

Comment: Can confirm it doesn't work in macOS Safari 15.2. But it works in iOS Safari.

Comment: @rosalynnas Hi, which version of browser, on macOS 12.3/12.0.1 and Safari 15.4/15.1, it working properly.

Comment: I checked my phone and it does work in IOS. I'm running Safari 15.4 and Monterey 12.3. From what I can see, theme-colour isn't working on any desktop sites for me at the moment, including the site I'm currently working on.

Comment: @rosalynnas I'm using same version like you. My friends using old version still working normal. Is it possible that some system preferences override theme-color feature?

Comment: I played around with a bunch of settings and it turns out having tab layout set to "separate" was the reason

Comment: @rosalynnas Thank you for testing, it made me confused many days 

Comment: @Roger Awesome!!!

P.s.: works (again?) in macOS Monterey 12.4 Beta (21F5048e) and Safari 15.5 (17613.2.4.1.2)

Comment: `Allow Website Tinting` must be enabled in iOS Safari settings. Otherwise it only work in PWA mode.

Comment: Make sure to set Safari in Settings/Tabs/'Tab Layout' to Compact! Still working for me...